# VB6 OCX not working in Windows 7 64 bit IE

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, activex

I have an old VB6 OCX which works fine on Windows 7 IE (32 bit), but it does not work on IE (64 bit).

Could someone please tell me the reason why its not working on IE (64 bit)? What are the possible options to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 64-bit version of IE only supports 64-bit add-ons. Your OCX is 32-bit so its not supported.

### The Visual Basic 6.0 IDE

> The Visual Basic 6.0 IDE is no longer supported as of April 8, 2008. However, Custom Support Agreements may be available from Microsoft. Additionally, both the Windows and Visual Basic teams have tested Visual Basic 6.0 IDE on Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, and Windows 8 to understand and mitigate (if appropriate) serious regressions in application compatibility. This announcement does not change the support policy for the IDE.

### The Visual Basic 6.0 Runtime

> The Visual Basic 6.0 runtime is defined as the compiled binary files originally included in the redistribution list for Visual Basic 6.0. These files were marked as distributable in the original Visual Basic 6.0 license. Examples of these files include the Visual Basic 6.0 runtime library (msvbvm60.dll), controls (i.e. msflxgrd.ocx) along with runtime support files for other major functional areas (i.e. MDAC).

The runtime is divided into the three groups:

### Supported Runtime Files

> Shipping in the OS: Key Visual Basic 6.0 runtime files, used in the majority of application scenarios, are shipping in and supported for the lifetime of Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, or Windows 8. This lifetime is five years of mainstream support and five years of extended support from the time that a given version of Windows ships. These files have been tested for compatibility as part of our testing of Visual Basic 6.0 applications running on Windows Vista. Note: the list of files shipping in Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows XP are nearly identical and redist requirements for applications should be nearly identical. One key difference is TriEdit.dll was removed from Windows Vista and later versions.

### Supported Runtime Files

> Extended Files to Distribute with your application: extended list of key controls, libraries, and tools that are installed from the IDE media or from Microsoft.com to the developer machine. Typically the VB6 IDE installed these controls to the developer machine by default. The developer still needs to redistribute these files with the application. The supported version of the files is available online on the Microsoft Download Center (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142927).

### Unsupported Runtime Files

> Some files have either fallen out of mainstream support or they were never included as a part of the runtime redist (e.g. they were included in \Tools folder on the IDE media to support legacy VB4/VB5 applications or they were 3rd party controls). These files are not supported on Windows; instead they are subject to whatever support agreement applies to the media they were shipped with. These files have been tested to work on Vista as part of our application compatibility and testing process, but this implies no warranties around support and servicing. In some instances, later versions of these libraries are supported. Details on backward compatibility or migration to supported versions are provided below.
>
> The Visual Basic 6.0 runtime has been tested for compatibility between Windows XP and Windows Vista / Windows Server 2008/Windows 7/Windows 8 with a goal that applications work similarly on these operating systems. As with any release of the operating system, there may be differences in functionality that will require modifications to your applications. These differences will be addressed on a case-by-case basis via normal support channels.

### 64-Bit Windows

> Visual Basic 6.0 runtime files are 32-bit. These files ship in 64-bit Windows Operating Systems referenced in the table below. 32-bit VB6 applications and components are supported in the WOW emulation environment only. 32-bit components must also be hosted in 32-bit application processes.
>
> The Visual Basic 6.0 IDE has never been offered in a native 64-bit version, nor has the 32-bit IDE been supported on 64-bit Windows. VB6 development on 64-bit Windows or any native architecture other than 32-bit is not and will not be supported.

### Windows 7

> Since the initial release of this support statement, the Windows 7 operating system has been announced. This document has been updated to clarify Microsoft’s support for VB6 on Windows 7.
>
> VB6 runtime will ship and will be supported in Windows 7 for the lifetime of the OS. Visual Basic 6.0 runtime files continue to be 32-bit only and all components must be hosted in 32-bit application processes. Developers can think of the support story for Windows 7 being the same as it is for Windows Vista.

### Windows 8

> Since the initial release of this support statement, the Windows 8 operating system has been announced. This document has been updated to clarify Microsoft’s support for VB6 on Windows 8.
>
> VB6 runtime will ship and will be supported in Windows 8 for the lifetime of the OS. Visual Basic 6.0 runtime files continue to be 32-bit only and all components must be hosted in 32-bit application processes. Developers can think of the support story for Windows 8 being the same as it is for Windows 7.

There is a huge chart I don't feel like trying to copy located [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx)

Comment: Can I recompile my OCX for 64-bit architecture? Is there any option available to compile OCX for 64-bit in Visual Studio 2000?

Comment: @Siddiqui - I don't believe Visual Basic 6 supported 64-bit assemblies.  Just use the 32-bit browser.

Comment: You are my saviour! I have spent hours and hours trying to get an old VB6 ActiveX to work on my machine, and now, after launching IE in 32bit, it finally runs! If I could upvote this more than once, you would drown in upvotes, mate. Thanks!